# what is the difference between a plank and a board?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

According to my study, a plank is a **long narrow** piece of wood and a board is a **thin flat** piece of wood.

Now if a piece of wood that is long and narrow and thin, is it a board?

and if a piece of wood that is thin and flat and narrow, is it a plank?

are a plank and a board types of lumber?

Comment: plank and board can mean the same thing. Boards, though, can be wide, whereas a plank is narrow. That is the main **semantic trait difference**: narrow versus possibly wide.

Comment: Idiomatic expression: to walk the plank {See pirates)

Comment: A plank is a long thick board that is rough-sawn,  and that is left "unfinished", that is, unplaned  and unjointed. A board can be sold rough-sawn, or it can be sold fully finished, planed and jointed, or finished on two faces only.  Boards can be short (say under 2 feet) or long (say 12 feet). Boards can be relatively thin (1/2, 3/4, 1 inch,);  above one inch thickness boards are referred to as 6/4, 8/4, and 12/4 boards in the US. Those are the standard nominal thicknesses.

Answer (score 3):

A plank is a piece of lumber, it is a long, narrow, flat, piece.  It has no particular purpose, and so could be used for anything where a piece of wood of that shape is needed. You could use several to make a floor, or to stop a door from being opened.  You could stick one out the side of your pirate boat and force people to walk off it.  A plank should be thick enough to support at least its own weight. Very thin strips of wood that have no structural use aren't planks.

A board is a flat and thin piece of wood (or other material) it might not be long and narrow, it could be squarish or even round.  It often has a particular purpose, and so combines with other words. A plank used to make a floor is a now a floorboard.  A board with words written on it is a signboard. A board with a checker pattern for playing games is a chessboard.  Paint it black and its a blackboard (or chalkboard).

Comment: A plank is a kind of board but a board is not a plank. Worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

**I believe the two words are close synonyms, and the context probably has most to do with which one is used.**

***Planks*** are used among other things to provide temporary bridging, loose walking surfaces - eg with scaffolding, and pirates "walk the plank". Planks are always long and narrow.

***Boards*** come in different shapes and sizes, and can be used for many things including writing surfaces - blackboards, flooring - floorboards (actors "tread the boards"), shuttering - the shop is "boarded-up", notices - notice boards, etc.